# Stopping text from fading along with the background color

Tags: html, css, hover, fade

I am creating 2 boxes that, on hover, fade to red but I want the text to remain completely white and not fade with the background/image. I am not very advanced in coding but any help will be appreciated along with a live demo if possible?

CSS

```
.image {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#555555;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.image img {
    width:50%;
    vertical-align:top;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.image:after, .image:before {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgba (255,0,0,1);
    opacity:0;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.image:after {
    content:'\A';
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.75);
    color:#ffffff;
}
.image:before {
    width:50%;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:0;
    padding:4px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.image:hover:after, .image:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
}
.text {
    padding-left:210px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-top:-190px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,10);
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor     incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to keep the Text in front just use `z-index` add this on your CSS:

```
.text {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Check this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qekazm4/1/)

*If you want the image in front too use the same property http://jsfiddle.net/2qekazm4/2/*

Answer (score 0):

Here you go my friend I put this in the fiddle and it worked out wonderfully let me know if it has problems, or isn't what you were wanting it to do. Here is a link to it

http://jsfiddle.net/sps5rxhg/

```
.image {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#555555;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.image img {
    width:50%;
    vertical-align:top;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.image:after, .image:before {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgba (255,0,0,1);
    opacity:0;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.image:after {
    content:'\A';
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.75);
    color:#ffffff;
}
.image:before {
    width:50%;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:0;
    padding:4px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.image:hover:after, .image:hover:before {
    opacity:.5;
}
.text {
    padding-left:210px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-top:-190px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,10);
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    opacity: 1;
        position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: `color:rgba(255,255,255,10);` ? the parameter for the opacity is between 0 and 1

Comment: Hi Mark - This is almost what I am after, however is it possible to make the image fade as well as the background behind the text without the text itself fading? Not sure if that made sense?

Comment: the range for opacity is not between but is 0 to 1 as in 0<=x<=1

Comment: So you are looking for the whole thing to be red with the white text remaining?

Answer (score 0):

Lets get to concept first.

> Opacity sets opacity of everything in the current block to which opacity is set.

So to get around this problem, **Do not use OPACITY. Instead use rgba.**

**In CSS:**

```
#outer-container {
  background: url(../img/image.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

#inner-container-for-alpha  {
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  background: rgba(43,255,113, 0.6); }
```

Where outer and inner container in **html** be like:

```
<div class="row" id="outer-container">
   <div id="inner-container-for-alpha ">
      <h1> This is text over image and it will not get faded </h1>
   </div>
</div>
```